# VS2010 extension help

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an extension idea, but I don't know where the first step is. I know that using design view, in conjunction with properties, I can get an event list for a control.

I want to write something that would show me a context menu in source view on something like OnClick="Button1_Click" and generate an empty event method in code behind complete with args. 
(the equivalant of double clicking a button in design view)

I've never coded against the IDE itself, and I'm not having any luck finding a jumping off point, but I relly want some info that relates to that 'events' section of the properties box.

EDIT: why am I getting negative numbers for asking a question, am I asking it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so admittedly, I did not ever figure out how to do this. However, I've just read the VS11 will be doing this. I am happy to see that M$ has added this functionality going forward. They've also added smart tags to the html view, which means maybe never having to go to design view again!

More Details Here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/08/31/html-editor-smart-tasks-and-event-handler-generation-asp-net-vnext-series.aspx

Answer (score 3):

MSDN will help :) See [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165343%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) [pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165736.aspx) on how to provide a custom properties window.

However, it won't be just as easy as your example, unfortunately.  There's quite a bit of infrastructure to deal with when programming VS extensions.  I'd recommend reading up on [VS Integration on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx).

Comment: I'm hoping that it would be simpler than a full window. If I can just tap into the fuctionality behind the events tab, that's all I'm really looking for is to bring that into source view

Comment: There isn't an extremely simple way like that simple OnClick event handler you described. Visual Studio just doesn't have that infrastructure.